# Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException

Tags: laravel, state, google-signin, laravel-socialite

Hi i am using laravel socialite for social logins with facebook and google and it absoultely working fine on my local server but when i deploy this on my web hosting it gives me error

> Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException
> it is only for when i try to login with google in my app but it is working fine for facebook  i tried many solutions as add `stateless()` in both google redirect method and callback method and single single too but all in vain i also tried to change in `config/session` where `domain` shows as `null` to my `site name` but again got same issue here is my code for google redirect and callback

```
public function redirectToGoogle()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}

 public function handleGoogleCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    $this->_registerOrLoginUser($user);
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
protected function _registerOrLoginUser($data)
{
    $user = User::where('email','=',$data->email)->first();
    if(!$user){
        $user = new User();
        $user->first_name = $data->name;
        $user->email = $data->email;
        // $user->provider_id = $data->provider_id;
        $user->avatar = $data->avatar;
        $user->save();
    }
    Auth::login($user);
}
```

please let me know if i'm missing something or doing wrong i'll appreciate your response in advance thank you

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate? In production, Google may only provide a code to a HTTPS endpoint to avoid it being intercepted.

Comment: can you show me APP_URL in ENV file?

Comment: @Chalas yes i have ssl certification

Comment: @kas this is my app url in env APP_URL=https://taptailor.co

Comment: app URL seems good. did you generate another API key for the production domain?

Comment: @kas yes exactly i created but doesn't work